# how can i install a tizen app in gear s2 with its name changed?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I have ever bulid a project called "alarm2" in tizen studio , but later I **change the app name** into "alarm4",when I clicked run as tizen application,then I can use the app, but when I quit the app ,I **can't find it** anywhere in gear s2,
so what should I do to keep the running app reserve in the gear s2?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check `nodisplay` property in tizen-manifest.xml? If it is true, your application is not shown in app list.

`<ui-application appid="org.example.alarm" exec="alarm" type="capp" multiple="false" taskmanage="true" nodisplay="false">`